# Что такое bloc Provider flutter

Tags: flutter

Если кто знает то объясните мне

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/475404/

Comment: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/ru/flutterbloccoreconcepts

Answer (score 0):

BlocProvider позволяет получить доступ к экземпляру Bloc/Cubit во всех дочерних виджетах через обращение к BuildContext.

```
var myBloc = BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>(context);
```

(Через контекст происходит перебор родителей данного виджета пока не найдется тот, в котором хранится экземпляр указанного в угловых скобках типа)

Подробнее - погуглите тему InheritedWidgets